# Unix : lookup value from one file to other files based on two joining keys

Tags: shell, unix

I'm looking for help on joining(at unix level) 2 files(file1 n file2), 
pickup values from file2 as a priority on file1. i.e if value in tmpValue exists on file2 that should be taken instead of file1 srcValue, if no tmpValue on file2 then use srcValue on  file1 tmpValue.
Note : lookup  has to be done based on 2 key columns : id and dept
sample

```
file1
------
id^dept^name^srcValue
1^d1^a^s123    
2^d2^b^s456    
3^d3^c^        

file2
--------

id^dept^name
1^d1^Tva
3^d3^TVb
4^d4^Tvm  

Desired output
---------------------
id^dept^name^FinalValue 
1^d1^a^Tva          
2^d2^b^s456         
3^d3^c^TVb
```

Below sample code works fine if i consider only 1 column as key  column(id), but I'm not sure how to mention both id and dept as key columns.

```
  awk -F"^" 'BEGIN{OFS="^"} 
               { 
            if (NR==FNR) { 
                a[$1]=$3;     
                next  
            }   
            if ($1 in a){
                $4=a[$1] 
            }
             print
           }' file2 file1 


output of same(above)code
id^dept^name^name
1^d1^a^Tva
2^d2^b^s456
3^d3^c^TVb
```

Comment: You said file2 has priority, so how does `1/d1` get `s123`as final value when file2 assigns `Tva`?

Comment: Consider adding `awk` tag. If you parse file1 first with `awk` then parse file2 to make overrides it is easy.

Comment: Thanks Mark, i have corrected desired output.

Comment: How are these tables defined in files?  Impossible to propose solutions based on tables (unless of course they *are* html tables in the files).  What have you tried?  Any research?

Comment: Table i just added(formatting) for posting question here. file1 and file2 are text files. i have rephrased the question in file format and the option which i tried.

Comment: If you want to use both `id` and `dept` as columns you can use `awk`'s SUBSEP https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multidimensional.html E.g. `a[id SUBSEP dept] = x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure how to mention both id and dept as key columns.

Store both.

```
a[$1, $2]=$3;
```

And compare both.

```
if (($1, $2) in a) {
```

Comma just "merges" values using `OFS`. So `$1, $2` is basically equal to `$1 OFS $2` - it's a string with `^` in between. You can `print ($1, $2)` for example to inspect it.